# Is it possible to rename "Tax" in WooCommerce check out?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am setting up a site that uses WooCommerce. We want to use variable pricing, with service fees attached to specific variations and removed from others. At the present, we discovered that using WooCommerce's system of taxes (Reduced, Regular, Zero) works well for us as we can denote which variations have fees and which do not.

The problem: We do not want the fee to be listed as "Tax" during check out. What do I need to edit to change the word "Tax" that shows up in check out totals to "Service Fee"?